# How to make COUNTIF return as either TRUE or FALSE

Tags: google-sheets

I have a formula that i want to return as either TRUE or FALSE, but it is returning 1 or 0.

```
=COUNTIF(X2, "Adv")
```

So if X2 = Adv i want to return the value TRUE

I also tried IF statement, but could not make it return TRUE or FALSE. So i added YES or NO instead.

```
=IF(X2="Adv","YES","NO")
```

Is there a similar formula or different method i can use to return TRUE or FALSE? Does it even matter? The reason i ask is because I have three other columns returning either TRUE or FALSE. I eventually want to check all four columns and return a value if they are all TRUE. And i want it to be as simple as possible. For Example:

```
=IF(AND(A2, C2, E2, X2),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Comment: Do you know that 1 and 0 are totally exchangeable for TRUE and FALSE when you use them in formulas? In fact, any number greater than 0 will be regarded as TRUE.

Comment: No, I didn't know that for sure. Thank you this helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler than that:

```
=A2="Adv"
```

That will return True/False.